# Ayuda JNI con lectura binarios C y escritura en Java

Tags: java, jni

Tengo que realizar un programa que lea archivos binarios de cualquier tipo desde C y por medio de JNI pasar los bytes leídos a java. Esa parte ya está, lo que me falta es escribir un nuevo archivo en Java y pasarle todos los datos que recopila C. Les pongo el código que tengo, gracias.

```
//C code
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_ReadFileJNI_readfile(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj)
{

//the variables are initialized
jstring str;
jsize len = 1;
jobjectArray objectarray = 0;

//Create variable rate "File" is prompter and call fopen "rb" -> leer archivo/tipo binario
FILE * flujo = fopen("Datos.txt","rb");

// Mueve el flujo al final del archivo, SEEK_END -> final del archivo  
fseek(flujo, 0 , SEEK_END);

/* Da la cantidad total de elementos ya que el ftell pregunta donde 
   se encuentra el flujo y eso se almacena en la variable 
*/
int num_elementos = ftell(flujo);

//Mueve el flujo al inicio del archivo
rewind(flujo);

/* Crear un arreglo de caracteres dinámico, calloc-> de que tamaño en bytes    va a ser cada elemento del arreglo 
   se le manda cuanta cantidad de elementos quiere reservar
*/
unsigned char * cadena = (unsigned char *) calloc(sizeof(unsigned char), num_elementos);

/* fread recibe un arreglo donde meterá todo el contenido del flujo y que    tamaño es elemento que se quiere leer
   y cuantos se quieren leer y como se quieren leer todos se pone el # de   elementos  y se le manda de donde 
   extraerá la información
*/
int num_elemetos_leidos = fread(cadena,sizeof(unsigned char),  num_elementos,flujo);

//Se realiza la asignación del arreglo para enviarlo    
objectarray = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,len,(*env)- >FindClass(env,"java/lang/String"),0);
str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,cadena);
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,objectarray,0,str);

//se libera memoria dinámica de la cadena y se cierra el flujo 
free(cadena);
fclose(flujo);
return objectarray;
}
```

Este es el código Java:

```
//código java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class ReadFileJNI
{
    native String[] readfile();

    static{ System.loadLibrary("ReadFileJNI"); }

    static public void main(String args[])
    {

      ReadFileJNI obj = new ReadFileJNI();
      String[] buffer = obj.readfile();

      System.out.println(" El arreglo desde C es: \n ");
      for(String name: buffer)
        System.out.println(name);

        try {

            //String content = name;
            File file = new File("ruta donde se creara el archivo");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(String name: buffer)
            System.out.println(name);
            bw.write(String name);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me da bastante mala espina el espacio en la ruta del fichero en tu archivo Java.

Comment: Si disculpa es que acabo de unirme a esto y no se muy bien como preguntar ya lo edite para que no se preste a malas interpretaciones

Comment: No me refería a eso. Tu pregunta estaba bien formulada. Me refería a que creo que eso es lo que puede darte error. El espacio que hay entre `pruebas  251016` me parece que es lo que te puede estar dando error en tu programa.

Comment: A ok, pero no ese no es el problema por que ese espacio solo corresponde al nombre de la carpeta el verdadero problema es que el "buffer" no es compactible con la forma de escribir en java que en este caso lo puse con un "BufferedWriter", le pongo la igualacion al String con la variable "name" pero tampoco, realmente no se Como imprimir el lo que se paso de C en un archivo nuevo, por que de echo si lo puedo imprimir pero solamente en consola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto

```
  for(String name: buffer){
        System.out.println(name);
        bw.write(name);
}            
bw.close();
```

En vez de esto:

```
for(String name: buffer) //Solo iteras System.
    System.out.println(name);
    bw.write(String name); //es error de compilación el String.
    bw.close();
```

Recuerda que el for solo altera al siguiente elemento y que en los objetos no se debe colocar el tipo de dato.

Comment: Perfecto si era eso lo que tenia, el codigo ya me funciona muy bien muchas gracias